# Substracting 15 minutes from current time. Javascript or php?

Tags: javascript, php, date, time

I need to round the actual date/time to nearest past 15 min. and calculate the 10 previous 15 min times.

For ex. 12/07/2014 16:25 should be rounded to 12/07/2014 16:15 and i must retrieve 12/07/2014 16:00, 15:45, 15:30, etc...
It must keep track of hour,day,month, year/leap year. I need all variables year/month/day/hour/minutes.

What is the easiest way to do that ? php or javascript ? any working script ?

I scratching my head...

Comment: Do you need to take time zones into account for the local machine?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I did overlook the duplicate question. I wrote it in php with the help of the codes published, and it works perfectly. But, unfortunately, i meanwhile discovered that i need to do it in javascript ! It seems to be much harder to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$currentDT   = new \DateTime('2011-12-13 14:15:16');
print_r($currentDT);
echo '</br>';
$filterRange = new \DateInterval('PT15M');
$filterDate  = clone $currentDT;
$filterDate->sub($filterRange);
print_r($filterDate) ;
```

**Output:**

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2011-12-13 14:15:16 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2011-12-13 14:00:16 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )
```